# entity query comes back null, how to check for it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have an entity query:

```
Location location = new Location();

var loc = from l in location.name
          where location.active = true
          select l;

return View(loc.ToList());
```

and the code, when run throws an issue because both name and active are null. This is fine, how ever, is there a way to say: if not empty return? would that be as simple as asking if `loc` is empty or not before returning it?

if so How would I do that?

### Further details

I am getting the error:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source

which happens on line:

```
var loc = (from l in location.name
```

My context class looks as such:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using LocationApp.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace LocationApp.DAL
{
    public class LocationAppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ServiceAssignment> ServiceAssignments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This approach is using the code first approach, I have one entry in my database for a location, it has a name and its "active" is set to true. So I can't see why this is spazzing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to return a single** Location, Use the `FirstOrDefault` method.

Also, you need to create an object of your DBContext class and access it's `Locations` property to get the locations.

```
using(var db=new LocationAppContext())
{
   var loc = (from l in db.Locations
                   where l.active == true
                   select l).FirstOrDefault();
   if(loc!=null)
      return View(loc);
   else
      return View("NotFound")
}
```

**If you are looking for a collection**, us `ToList()` on your expression and you can check the `Count` property to see any items are returned or not

```
using(var db=new LocationAppContext())
{
   var loc = (from l in db.Locations
                  where l.active == true
                  select l).ToList();
   if(loc.Count>0)
      return View(loc);
   else
      return View("NotFound")
}
```

Comment: Just something to add, I keep getting the exception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source.

Comment: @TheWebs Also you may need 2 `=` in the LINQ expression.

Comment: `var loc = (from l in location.name` I am using the code first approach for this. So I am not sure if there is something I should se tin my model or not...And there is a location in the database

Comment: Is `location` your DBContext class object ? How does it look ?

Comment: @TheWebs: Please post your relevant DBContext class

Comment: @TheWebs: Checkout this sample to understand how to use your DBcontext and get the entities.  http://www.techiesweb.net/starting-entity-framework-codefirst-approach-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

your location will be ever null, if in default constructor it does not populate
fields/properties

try this

```
var location = new Location { name= "dsd", active = true};

var tmp = location.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.active);

var loc = tmp == null ? String.Empty : tmp.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The source collection of your Linq query is an `IEnumerable<char>` which is implemented by `string` (I guess `Location.Name` is a `string`) and you would return a list of characters to your view. (Do you really want this?)

Anyway, the source collection must not be `null`. You must catch this case *before* the Linq query. If it's `null` you can't use this Linq query at all.

```
Location location = new Location();

List<char> loc = null;
if (location.name != null)
    loc = (from l in location.name
           where location.active.HasValue && location.active.Value
           select l).ToList();
else
    loc = new List<char>();

return View(loc);
```

But this has nothing to do with Entity Framework. It's just an in-memory query (LINQ-to-Objects).